# Copying specific output of traceroute and ping commands into a file

Tags: ping, traceroute

I'm fairly new into Linux, so don't be harsh on me :)
I'm currently sitting under ISP's CGNAT, and the only way I can connect to my home server outside of the network is by accessing it through WAN IP (which can be seen in router admin page). I've found that by entering

```
traceroute -n 8.8.8.8
```

then copying thrid IP adress and putting it into ping command

```
ping -c 3 -R x.x.x.x
```

gives me the output of the WAN IP.

I'm searching the way to copy that WAN IP into a file and pasting it into config file of ddclient ddclient.conf.

If therese any more elegant solution for what I'm trying to achieve it would be very nice!

Comment: I think the most elegant way here would be surprisingly simple: just use the global address your ISP does give you. It's the IPv6 address you most likely have!

Comment: Unfortunately, my ISP only supports IPv4

Comment: CGNAT + IPv4 only are a bad (and rare) combination. Saw that with old vodafone cable tv accesses only, so far, luckily!

Answer (score 1):

Using `ping` and `traceroute` for this isn't necessarily helpful, as they use [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) as protocol, and many systems are configured not to respond to ICMP echo requests for security reasons. Example from my system:

```
pg@TREX:~$ traceroute -n 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1  0.699 ms  0.594 ms  0.800 ms
 2  213.243.152.36  25.235 ms * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  142.250.169.179  26.723 ms  26.534 ms  26.464 ms
 6  142.250.169.178  34.509 ms  34.216 ms  34.234 ms
 7  * * *
 8  8.8.8.8  21.684 ms  24.621 ms  16.712 ms
```

The asterisks denote systems that didn't respond.

`dig` gives handily what you're looking for:

```
pg@TREX:~$ dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
XX.YY.50.178
```

If you get an empty result, disable IPv6 before `dig`ging.

```
pg@TREX:~$ ip add show dev enp11s0
2: enp11s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 78:f2:9e:f6:1c:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.220/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp11s0
       valid_lft 86262sec preferred_lft 86262sec
    inet6 2001:96ab:c4:3c0a:ec56:2319:9a63:3/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 7064sec preferred_lft 3464sec
    inet6 fdec:5623:b43a:a2a9:9039:d8ab:961f:bd6c/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 7074sec preferred_lft 3474sec
    inet6 2001:14bb:a2:6830:28de:50f1:f2db:9ebf/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 7074sec preferred_lft 3474sec
    inet6 fe80::9f5b:debb:1215:54e2/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
pg@TREX:~$ dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
pg@TREX:~$
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm not near my server atm, can't try this. Are you sure that this dig command print private WAN ip and not public ip adress?

Comment: I clarified that my ISP is using CGNAT  (also known as large-scale NAT), is a method of sharing a single unique public IP address with multiple services to allow providers to extend their pool of usable IPv4 addresses. This means my router will be assigned a private IP address instead of a unique public IP address.  That means that the IP address services like myip.com prints out differs from IP address I can access my server with.

Comment: Ideal solution would be to buy static IP from my ISP, but that doubles what I'm currently paying.

Comment: Right - I took "GNAT" for a typo for "NAT" :-D In that case @MarcusMüller's comment is the easiest way. Any specific reason why that's not appropriate? Does the IP your ISP gives keep changing? Or you just want to find an elegant way to get it from the CLI like a proper nerd? :-)

Comment: Yes, I have a dynamic IP address, and the cost ISP charging for the static one is unreasonably high :D

Comment: Now that's a damn sight more interesting problem :-) I've not actually dabbled with CGNAT before - does your ISP then do any kind of port forwarding to your network? A couple of things that might be useful at least as pointers: [pwnat](https://github.com/samyk/pwnat), [Tailscale](https://tailscale.com)

Comment: thanks for your answers! I will look into your suggestions

Comment: Tried Tailscale - works like a charm! Thanks a lot. Would've upvoted your reply, but my reputation is not yet high enough :)

Comment: No matter, just great I was able to help :-) If you'd be kind to accept the answer on the `pwnat` question so it doesn't pop up two years from now as "unanaswered"... unless the binary didn't get built for you as it did for me, of course.

Answer (score 0):

There are several sites on the net that will tell you what IP address you connected with.  One of them which I find useful is http://ifconfig.me (this works with either http or https protocols.  viewing this in a browser will show you your IP address plus some details about your browser, and instructions for command-line usage)

You can fetch the IP on the command line with `curl`.  e.g.

```
curl ifconfig.me
```

That will return just your IP address, no html, nothing else, not even a newline after the IP.

I use it with the following trivial wrapper script:

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/what-is-my-ip.sh
#!/bin/sh

unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy

curl ifconfig.me
echo
```